# What is this herbaceous plant that I grew from seeds?

Tags: identification

Please help me identify this plant:

[image: unknown plant]

We just got some seeds and this grew. Unfortunately, these seeds might not even be local, so telling you that I'm in Austria won't be much help.

Comment: Wow that is a tough one, any chance to give us more info on the top of it.  Does it appear to be flowering or what does the top of this thing look like ?

Comment: Looks like an Asiatic lily but not positive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Dianthus barbatus, commonly know as "Sweet William".

[Wikipedia article:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dianthus_barbatus)

> Dianthus barbatus (Sweet William) is a species of Dianthus native to southern Europe and parts of Asia which has become a popular ornamental garden plant. It is a herbaceous biennial or short-lived perennial plant growing to 30–75 cm tall, with flowers in a dense cluster of up to 30 at the top of the stems. Each flower is 2–3 cm diameter with five petals displaying serrated edges. Wild plants produce red flowers with a white base, but colours in cultivars range from white, pink, red, and purple to variegated patterns. The exact origin of its English common name is unknown but first appears in 1596 in botanist John Gerard's garden catalogue. The flowers are edible and may have medicinal properties. Sweet William attracts bees, birds, and butterflies.

Culture: http://homeguides.sfgate.com/care-dianthus-barbatus-65887.html

[Images for comparison to help identify cross/type.](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Dianthus%20barbatus&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisr4LW_oLNAhVJ2oMKHW43ANMQ_AUIBygB&biw=1680&bih=886)